Looking for algorithm to fit puzzle pieces into a 2D matrix
I have a game board which is a 2D array of letters - 6 x 8. The objective is to find a list of words with the length equal to X that complete the matrix without a letter being used twice. To create a word you can go up, down, left, right, and all diagonals. There is one word that going all the way from left to right, right to left, up to down, or down to up. This word describes the theme of the rest of the words.
My original solution was to use a backtracking algorithm to find all the possible words in the 2D matrix. From this, I would use another backtracking algorithm to find the combination of words that complete the matrix. I imagined each word being a puzzle piece that when put together it would complete the matrix with no overlaps. The list of possible words was much longer than I expected, averaging 1500 words. Since the list length is so long it causes the second backtracking algorithm to be 2^1500 which will never finish. So my first thought was I need to reduce the number of words in the possible words list. I tried to find a dictionary that had reduced words but I always ran into one that missed a word or two that were used to complete the matrix. Another solution I thought of was to use ChatGPT to analyze the theme and filter the list based off that. But GPT doesn't perform well in this regard. If anyone has any suggestions or comments I am very open to anything.
Here is the code below:
run.py
from DictionaryAVLTree import dictionaryAVLTree, MINIMUM_WL, MAXIMUM_WL

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 6, 8
outputFile = open("strands_words.txt", "w")

# strandsArray = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
strandsArray = [['e', 'w' ,'r', 'p', 'b', 'r'],
                ['n', 'e', 'u', 'b', 'o', 'w'],
                ['e', 'm', 'c', 'i', 'l', 's'],
                ['e', 'l', 'o', 'r', 'r', 'e'],
                ['t', 'd', 'i', 'w', 'o', 'b'],
                ['y', 'u', 'b', 'r', 'a', 'r'],
                ['r', 'e', 't', 'r', 'n', 'a'],
                ['a', 'd', 's', 'y', 'l', 'e']]
totalWords = 6
# strandsArray = [
#     ['t', 'h', 'i', 's'],
#     ['w', 'a', 't', 's'],
#     ['o', 'a', 'h', 'g'],
#     ['f', 'g', 'd', 't']
# ]

# Backtracking recursive function to find words in 2D Matrix
# @Params
def searchLetter(currentString, row, col, usedLettersSet, usedLettersArray, possibleWords):
    # Check if the row and col is in bounds if its not then return false
    if not isInBounds(row, col):
        return

    # if the string is too long then just return
    if len(currentString) + 1 >= MAXIMUM_WL:
        return
    
    # 3 Possible conditions:
    #   1. Got to end of tree
    #   2. Found a sub string
    #   3. Found a word

    # If the word is less than the minimum then dont check and just process the next possible letter
    if len(currentString) >= MINIMUM_WL:
        searchResults = dictionaryAVLTree.search_value(currentString)
    
        if searchResults['isSubString'] == False:
            return
        elif searchResults['isWord'] == True:
            possibleWords.append(usedLettersArray.copy())
            outputFile.write(currentString + '\n')

    # all possible directions to check
    directions = [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, 1), (1, 1), (1, -1), (-1, -1)]

    for direction in directions:
        newRow, newCol = row + direction[0], col + direction[1]
        searchNextLetter(currentString, newRow, newCol, usedLettersSet, usedLettersArray, possibleWords)

def searchNextLetter(currentString, row, col, usedLettersSet, usedLettersArray, possibleWords):
    # Makes sure it is a valid element in the 2D matrix and also it hasnt been used yet
    if isInBounds(row, col) and getId(row, col) not in usedLettersSet:
        usedLettersSet.add(getId(row, col))
        usedLettersArray.append(getId(row, col))

        searchLetter(currentString + strandsArray[row][col], row, col, usedLettersSet, usedLettersArray, possibleWords)

        usedLettersSet.remove(getId(row, col))
        usedLettersArray.remove(getId(row, col))

# Backtracking recursive function to complete the 2D matrix with words
def completeMatrix(start, usedLettersSet, usedWords, completedMatrixWords, possibleWords, matrixArea, totalWords, currentTotalWords):
    print(usedWords)
    if len(usedLettersSet) == matrixArea:
        completedMatrixWords.append(usedWords.copy())
        return
    
    if currentTotalWords >= totalWords:
        return
    
    if len(usedWords) >= totalWords:
        return
    
    if len(usedLettersSet) > matrixArea:
        return
    
    for index in range(start, len(possibleWords)):
        # Check that non of the letters in this word are in the usedLettersSet
        word = possibleWords[index]
        if all(letter not in usedLettersSet for letter in word):
            for letter in word:
                usedLettersSet.add(letter)
            usedWords.append(word)
            
            if completeMatrix(index + 1, usedLettersSet, usedWords, completedMatrixWords, possibleWords, matrixArea, totalWords, currentTotalWords + 1):
                return True  # Early termination if one solution is sufficient
            
            usedWords.pop()
            for letter in word:
                usedLettersSet.remove(letter)
                


# Helper Functions
def isInBounds(row, col):
    if (row < 0 or row >= len(strandsArray)) or (col < 0 or col >= len(strandsArray[0])):
        return False
    
    return True

def getId(row, col):
    return f"{row}#{col}"

# Main
def main():
    # For loop to iterate through strandsArray. Each element we do the algorithm
    possibleWords = []
    for row in range(len(strandsArray)):
        for col in range(len(strandsArray[0])):
            searchLetter(strandsArray[row][col], row, col, {getId(row, col)}, [getId(row, col)], possibleWords)
    
    completedMatrixWords = []
    # completeMatrix(0, set(), [], completedMatrixWords, possibleWords, len(strandsArray) * len(strandsArray[0]), totalWords, 0)
    # print(completedMatrixWords)
    for word in possibleWords:
        print(word)

main()
outputFile.close()


DictionaryAVLTree.py
from AVLTree import Node, AVLTree
import sys

# Constants
MINIMUM_WL = 4
MAXIMUM_WL = 15

# Function to simulate a dynamic print
def dynamic_print(text):
    sys.stdout.write('\r' + text)
    sys.stdout.flush()

dictionaryAVLTree = AVLTree()

print("[Creating Dict AVL Tree]")

with open("words_alpha.txt", "r") as file:
  counter = 0
  for word in file:
    currWord = word.strip()
    if len(currWord) >= MINIMUM_WL and len(currWord) <= MAXIMUM_WL:
      dictionaryAVLTree.insert_value(currWord)
      counter += 1
      dynamic_print(f"{counter} words added")

print()
print("[Finished Dict AVL Tree]")

AVLTree.py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.height = 1


class AVLTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def height(self, node):
        if not node:
            return 0
        return node.height

    def balance(self, node):    
        if not node:
            return 0
        return self.height(node.left) - self.height(node.right)

    def insert(self, root, value):
        if not root:
            return Node(value)
        elif value < root.value:
            root.left = self.insert(root.left, value)
        else:
            root.right = self.insert(root.right, value)

        root.height = 1 + max(self.height(root.left), self.height(root.right))
        balance = self.balance(root)

        # Left rotation
        if balance > 1 and value < root.left.value:
            return self.right_rotate(root)

        # Right rotation
        if balance < -1 and value > root.right.value:
            return self.left_rotate(root)

        # Left-Right rotation
        if balance > 1 and value > root.left.value:
            root.left = self.left_rotate(root.left)
            return self.right_rotate(root)

        # Right-Left rotation
        if balance < -1 and value < root.right.value:
            root.right = self.right_rotate(root.right)
            return self.left_rotate(root)

        return root

    def delete(self, root, value):
        if not root:
            return root

        if value < root.value:
            root.left = self.delete(root.left, value)
        elif value > root.value:
            root.right = self.delete(root.right, value)
        else:
            if not root.left:
                temp = root.right
                root = None
                return temp
            elif not root.right:
                temp = root.left
                root = None
                return temp

            temp = self.min_value_node(root.right)
            root.value = temp.value
            root.right = self.delete(root.right, temp.value)

        if not root:
            return root

        root.height = 1 + max(self.height(root.left), self.height(root.right))
        balance = self.balance(root)

        # Left rotation
        if balance > 1 and self.balance(root.left) >= 0:
            return self.right_rotate(root)

        # Right rotation
        if balance < -1 and self.balance(root.right) <= 0:
            return self.left_rotate(root)

        # Left-Right rotation
        if balance > 1 and self.balance(root.left) < 0:
            root.left = self.left_rotate(root.left)
            return self.right_rotate(root)

        # Right-Left rotation
        if balance < -1 and self.balance(root.right) > 0:
            root.right = self.right_rotate(root.right)
            return self.left_rotate(root)

        return root

    def left_rotate(self, z):
        y = z.right
        T2 = y.left

        y.left = z
        z.right = T2

        z.height = 1 + max(self.height(z.left), self.height(z.right))
        y.height = 1 + max(self.height(y.left), self.height(y.right))

        return y

    def right_rotate(self, z):
        y = z.left
        T3 = y.right

        y.right = z
        z.left = T3

        z.height = 1 + max(self.height(z.left), self.height(z.right))
        y.height = 1 + max(self.height(y.left), self.height(y.right))

        return y

    def min_value_node(self, root):
        current = root
        while current.left:
            current = current.left
        return current

    def search(self, root, value, output=None):
        if not output:
            output={'isWord':False, 'isSubString':False}
        # We made it through the AVL and didnt find a word so we will just return
        if not root:
            return output
        
        # Check to see if the value is a sub string of a word meaning there exists a possible combination we can find in the 2d matrix that includes this substring
        if not output['isSubString'] and value == root.value[:len(value)]:
            output['isSubString'] = True
        
        # We found a word
        if root.value == value:
            output['isWord'] = True
            return output
        
        if root.value < value:
            return self.search(root.right, value, output)
        return self.search(root.left, value, output)

    def insert_value(self, value):
        self.root = self.insert(self.root, value)

    def delete_value(self, value):
        self.root = self.delete(self.root, value)

    def search_value(self, value):
        return self.search(self.root, value)

Download words_alpha.txt:
words_alpha.txt

Can you provide enough information that others can try running your code? For example, words_alpha.txt is not provided.

Sounds like a trie would be useful, but it is unclear to me what the task is. What is X? Do you have a count?

@Neil X is the number of words that need to be found to complete the 2D matrix. The words are already predefined and are different with every game board/2D matrix. The number of words that need to be found could be different for each game board. The task is to find all the words that complete the 2D matrix that don't overlap and follow a theme. The theme can be found by finding a word that stretches all the way from the top to bottom or from the left to the right and vise versa. Ill look into a trie and see what I can do with it

@NickODell Thanks for letting me know! I added a link to the word list that I used.

Once you have a set of words in the grid, you can use knuth's algorithm X (maybe with "dancing links") to find a solution. It's still essentially a backtracking algorithm, but with the idea that you identify constrained squares and try to cover those first. For example arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0011047, with the documented solver implemented by Dana Scott for pentonimos covering a chessboard in 1958.

to be clear: 1. find all words in the grid (with their grid squares) -- sounds like you've done this already. 2. form an exact cover problem (columns=squares on the grid, rows=grid words that you've found-- it's easier to formulate than a pentonimo cover or sudoku). 3. solve the exact cover problem using algorithm X/dancing links.

I'm still not sure about the rules. Does the user know X? Can you change directions once you've started a word, or is this like a crossword, one direction? Are you guaranteed that the words will be unique? But intersections are not allowed? Are you choosing all pre-set words of which there is a one-to-one correspondence in the puzzle, or any of a dictionary of words? (A trie would be more helpful with a very large search space because it allows you to eliminate prefixes.)

@PaulHankin Thank you for your response. I did some more research into Algorithm X/Dancing Links, and this is exactly what I need. I will keep you updated on my progress!
